# Get hold of a list of vst presets / parameters?

Tags: vst

So I'm trying to misuse a VST in my DAW, Reaper, for musical things. Basically I want to be able to write to and read from different files using VSTs.

The VST I'm using has a string option (which gets saved and restores using presets). I want to look under the hood a bit to see what is going to see if I can do what I want.

Is it possible to get a list of presets from the VST - or does a VST just output raw "data" for presets that can't be understood. Also what is the relationship between presets and midi automation - is every parameter in a VST settable from your DAW? I found a bunch of preset ini files in reaper, but they seemed to just contain binary data.

## Resources found so far

- I found this thread  https://forum.cockos.com/showthread.php?t=114458 that is using the reaper api to set parameters and also an API.
- There is a UI control in the FX pain in reaper, which shows sliders instead of the graphical interface. However, string values don't seem to be there.

Comment: It’s going to depend. Some presets will be stored in files or as files and so parsing those files or folders could get you a list. Others will use other systems for their preset “databases”. If you want to do something original with a plug-in I suggest you check out Max MSP, which is a visual IDE for audio plugins.

Comment: Reaper has its own presets. VST format also has its own presets (fxb and fxp). Particular plugi-ins usually have their own preset format on top.

MIDI standard has a standardized "instrument" list and a semi-standardized "control" list, and implementation varies. You could bet that almost any plug-in implements a MIDI control 1 modulation as vibrato, 7 as preset volume, 9 as pan (correct me if i''m wrong).

Since you're a lucky Reaper user, there is plenty of superficial programming you can do to extract parameters from a single preset - but I myself am still getiing the hang of it.

Comment: To give you an example, I've tried translating an Ableton Live preset into another plug-in format, but it's a "deep" XML hierarchy, and simply takes too much time. That is to say, most presets for decent instruments and or effects, will be unreadable, even if you can access all of the data